# Ajax posting a form returns undefined error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to submit a form with ajax. Here is my complete code

```
<?php 
    $wparent = "123";
    $method = "sms";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#post_<?php echo $wparent;?>").click(function(){
            $('#parentpost-<?php echo $wparent;?>').html('Loading.....');
            $("#parentpost-<?php echo $wparent;?>").load("<?php echo SITE_URL;?>new_ajax/post_reply.php", {message:$("[name=replynote]").val(), method:$("[name=method]").val(), parent:$("[name=parent]").val()}); //end
        }); // end of the main click function
    });
</script>

<?php   
echo "<textarea name='replynote' ></textarea>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"post_button\" id=\"post_$wparent\" value=\"post\" />";
echo "<input type=\"button\" class=\"cancel_button\" value=\"Cancel\" />";
?>
<input type='hidden' name='parent' value='<?php echo $wparent;?>' />
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="<?php echo $method;?>" />
```

When I checked the post variables with firebug I saw that, its sending only the method correctly. All other values are sent as undefined. I could not find the error till now.

Comment: how tuff to understand these code :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pre-populating the `data` map that you're passing:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#post_<?php echo $wparent;?>").click(function () {
         var message = $("[name=replynote]").val();
         var method = $("[name=method]").val();
         var parent = $("[name=parent]").val();
         var data = {
             "message": message,
             "method": method,
             "parent": parent
         };
         $('#parentpost-<?php echo $wparent;?>').html('Loading.....');
         $("#parentpost-<?php echo $wparent;?>").load("<?php echo SITE_URL;?>new_ajax/post_reply.php", data); //end
     }); // end of the main click function
 });
```

If `data` is an object containing `undefined` values, then your jQuery selectors aren't working.

Also, since you're only using a `name` attribute to find your inputs, you may want to be more specific in the selectors.

Finally, the `attribute` selectors typically need the value of the attribute enclosed in quotes, so try these for your selectors:

```
     var message = $('textarea[name="replynote"]').val();
     var method = $('input[name="method"]').val();
     var parent = $('input[name="parent"]').val();
```